# IIS URL rewrite 404 errors

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am running the config below to rewrite for example

http://www.phusewebdesign.co.uk/blog/Get-in-touch

to

http://www.phusewebdesign.co.uk/index.php?s=blog&p=Get-in-touch

but I get a 404 error, I am missing something simple I am sure but can't fimd the answer on google or here

thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?s={R:1}&amp;p={R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?p={R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What is `url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$"` supposed to match? Why do you have 2 rules? Have you tried to run the [Failed Request Tracing tool](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules)?

Comment: Hi, thanks I have solved it now. I recycled the app pool and the code started working.